# Zend MySQL PDO and remote host fatal error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo, remote-access, mysql-error-2002

At my local zend project I've got such problem, when I try to connect to remote mysql server.

Here application.ini part:

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = www.my-site.com
resources.db.params.port = 3306
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 123
resources.db.params.dbname = mydb
```

When I refreshing page appears such error:

```
Fatal error: in D:\_www\enoiq.lcl\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 145
```

print_r($e->getMessage()); before line with error shows:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
```

Where my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Remote access Enebled on Server?

Comment: MySQL is running?  Your error is 'ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket'.  Check firewall.  Try connecting from your MySQL GUI tool or command line?  Does that work?

Comment: yes, it is working - site copy located on remote host - is working as planned.